# The first item in my gridview was not being displayed at the start of the activity.

Tags: android, gridview

Sorry if this is an inappropriate question for SO. I have read over many similar questions but did not find a solution from them. In the code I am posting below, my workaround is shown in the ImageAdapter class that I have.

I am working on a small app and have an activity which includes a GridView. Below are my ImageAdapter and the Java class for the activity I am speaking of:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

int[] images = {
        R.mipmap.blackrook, R.mipmap.blackknight, R.mipmap.blackbishop, R.mipmap.blackqueen,
        R.mipmap.blackking, R.mipmap.blackbishop, R.mipmap.blackknight, R.mipmap.blackrook,
        R.mipmap.blackpawn, R.mipmap.blackpawn, R.mipmap.blackpawn, R.mipmap.blackpawn,
        R.mipmap.blackpawn, R.mipmap.blackpawn, R.mipmap.blackpawn, R.mipmap.blackpawn,
        R.mipmap.whitesquare, R.mipmap.blacksquare, R.mipmap.whitesquare, R.mipmap.blacksquare,
        R.mipmap.whitesquare, R.mipmap.blacksquare, R.mipmap.whitesquare, R.mipmap.blacksquare,
        R.mipmap.blacksquare, R.mipmap.whitesquare, R.mipmap.blacksquare, R.mipmap.whitesquare,
        R.mipmap.blacksquare, R.mipmap.whitesquare, R.mipmap.blacksquare, R.mipmap.whitesquare,
        R.mipmap.whitesquare, R.mipmap.blacksquare, R.mipmap.whitesquare, R.mipmap.blacksquare,
        R.mipmap.whitesquare, R.mipmap.blacksquare, R.mipmap.whitesquare, R.mipmap.blacksquare,
        R.mipmap.blacksquare, R.mipmap.whitesquare, R.mipmap.blacksquare, R.mipmap.whitesquare,
        R.mipmap.blacksquare, R.mipmap.whitesquare, R.mipmap.blacksquare, R.mipmap.whitesquare,
        R.mipmap.whitepawn, R.mipmap.whitepawn, R.mipmap.whitepawn, R.mipmap.whitepawn,
        R.mipmap.whitepawn, R.mipmap.whitepawn, R.mipmap.whitepawn, R.mipmap.whitepawn,
        R.mipmap.whiterook, R.mipmap.whiteknight, R.mipmap.whitebishop, R.mipmap.whitequeen,
        R.mipmap.whiteking, R.mipmap.whitebishop, R.mipmap.whiteknight, R.mipmap.whiterook,

};

private Context context;

public ImageAdapter(Context context){
    this.context = context;
}

public int[] getImages(){
    return images;
}

public int getCount(){
    return images.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position){
    return images[position];
}

public long getItemId(int position){
    return images[position];
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    ImageView iv = null;

    //if(convertView != null){
       // iv = (ImageView) convertView;
    //}//else{
        iv = new ImageView(context);
        iv.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(parent.getHeight()/8,
                parent.getWidth()/8));

        iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        iv.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    //}

    iv.setImageResource(images[position]);

    return iv;
}
```

}

The few lines in getView that are commented out were removed by me to work around the issue of the first GridView item not showing up when the activity first started. Before I made that change, the item at position 0 in the Adapter did not appear and did not respond to the listener that is set for each ImageView.

Here is the xml for the GridView:

```
<GridView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
    android:id="@+id/board"
    android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:numColumns="8" />
```

So, it seems to be working now. The first item (and all the rest) appear as they should and respond appropriately. I am here to ask if there are any issues that could arise from what I've done in getView. I am entirely new to Android development, and what I've done seems pretty hackish to me as compared to all of the other getView examples I have seen. Any advice/opinions ( I know this is frowned upon, sorry :/ ) would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The code you commented is actually good, it is used to recycle the views.

Just check out this example from the Google documentation, it is exactly what you need:
[GridView adapter](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html)

Adapter:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        return imageView;
    }

    // references to our images
    private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
            R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
            R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7
    };
}
```

Call in the Activity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(HelloGridView.this, "" + position,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Yes, I had thought the code I commented out was good at first as well. However, commenting it out was the only thing that fixed my issue. So, judging from your response, leaving that code commented out will work fine, but just eliminates the recycling? If a lack of performance is the only issue, I am fine with it, as there is not a huge amount of work going on elsewhere anyway. Thank you!